# Converting string to Date and DateTime

Tags: php, string, datetime, date

If I have a PHP string in the format of `mm-dd-YYYY` (for example, 10-16-2003), how do I properly convert that to a `Date` and then a `DateTime` in the format of `YYYY-mm-dd`? The only reason I ask for both `Date` and `DateTime` is because I need one in one spot, and the other in a different spot.

Comment: Best will be using DateTime in php 5 & 7. Detail blog: http://sforsuresh.in/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime-PHP

Comment: how convert to 10th  January 2020 to timeamp?

Answer (score 582, accepted):

Use `strtotime()` on your first date then `date('Y-m-d')` to convert it back:

```
$time = strtotime('10/16/2003');

$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);

echo $newformat;
// 2003-10-16
```

Make note that there is a difference between using forward slash `/` and hyphen `-` in the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) function. To quote from php.net:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats
> are disambiguated by looking at the
> separator between the various
> components: if the separator is a
> slash (/), then the American m/d/y is
> assumed; whereas if the separator is a
> dash (-) or a dot (.), then the
> European d-m-y format is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or **DateTime::createFromFormat()** when possible.

Comment: This won't work. PHP will interpret that input as DD-MM-YYYY.

Comment: @delive your date string is most likely not a correct date.

Comment: Yes I solved this problem with " str_replace('/', '-', $var);"  after apply "date('Y-m-d'....' and works well

Comment: It doesn't work because this answer is misleading. `strtotime` accepts certain formats. You can't feed it whatever. That's why `DateTime::createFromFormat` should be used instead of `strtotime`. Sadly, this answer has too many upvotes for anyone to pay attention. It's all copy paste these days.

Comment: One function should be added like this for better output: $newformat = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$time) );

Comment: I'm not sure why PHP assumes d-m-Y while ISO 8601 was created in 1988 which states date should be in format YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Please correct your answer, at some point sentence `If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.` added to the quote you have here. meaning if 4 digit year included as first token, it will be `yyyy-mm-dd` and if it is the last then `dd-mm-yyyy` is assumed. a `xx-xx-xx` format will always be considered as `yy-mm-dd`

Comment: Bit offtopic but worth noting for others because easily forgotten (IMO):
be cautios with dateformats like dd.mm.yy because it could be parsed as time. For example date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('05.03.21')) results in todays date with 05:03:21 for the time.

Comment: Or Simply use following code $time = ;

`$newformat = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('10/16/2003'));`

Comment: I want to know how to get the year of a date from the database. I passed it as a parameter in the function and did something like: $dt = ($detData == 'yyyy') ? " auto_dtinfr " : " NULL "; I need to implement a to_char. How to do?

Answer (score 529):

You need to be careful with m/d/Y and m-d-Y formats. PHP considers `/` to mean m/d/Y and `-` to mean d-m-Y. I would explicitly describe the input format in this case:

```
$ymd = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '10-16-2003')->format('Y-m-d');
```

That way you are not at the whims of a certain interpretation.

Comment: Curious as to why this isn't the accepted answer...  This is much more flexible than relying on the quirks of the `strtotime()` function.

Comment: It's important to point that php **DateTime** class is available since PHP  version 5.2 and _createFromFormat_ since 5.3

Comment: As with every function, you should check if it meets minimum version you must support. But PHP 5.2 EOL was Jan 2011. Nobody should be running it any more; catering to those people is just enabling them to run outdated, insecure software.

Comment: @Matthew yes, correct. But you never now, even today I found a PHP4.1 version still installed ...

Comment: This should be the best answer +1

Comment: I agree with commenters saying **this** should be the **accepted answer,** unless for some godforsaken reason you happen to be stuck with PHP 4 point something. In that case, date formatting ought to be the least of your worries.

Answer (score 34):

To parse the date, you should use:
    DateTime::createFromFormat();

Ex:

```
$dateDE = "16/10/2013";
$dateUS = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y", $dateDE)->format("m/d/Y");
```

However, careful, because this will crash with:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

You actually need to check that the formatting went fine, first:

```
$dateDE = "16/10/2013";
$dateObj = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y", $dateDE);
if (!$dateObj)
{
    throw new \UnexpectedValueException("Could not parse the date: $date");
}
$dateUS = $dateObj->format("m/d/Y");
```

Now instead of crashing, you will get an exception, which you can catch, propagate, etc.

$dateDE has the wrong format, it should be "16.10.2013";

Comment: Notice that checking $dateObj that way would only asure that the format matches the mask, not that the date is actually valid. For example, a date like 99/99/2010 would pass this check since it matches m/d/Y but it's not a date that you usually want to allow. This answer addresses this situation -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/10120725/995014

Answer (score 26):

```
$d = new DateTime('10-16-2003');

$timestamp = $d->getTimestamp(); // Unix timestamp
$formatted_date = $d->format('Y-m-d'); // 2003-10-16
```

Edit: you can also pass a DateTimeZone to DateTime() constructor to ensure the creation of the date for the desired time zone, not the server default one.

Comment: I believe this will throw an exception because month 16 is invalid.

Comment: It's important to point that php **DateTime** class is available since PHP  version 5.2 and _getTimestamp_ since 5.3

Answer (score 10):

Since no one mentioned this, here's another way:

```php
$date = date_create_from_format("m-d-Y", "10-16-2003")->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution. IMHO. Bravo.

Answer (score 10):

To create a date from any string you can use:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y H:i', '01-01-01 01:00');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have the date formatted as "07/May/2018" and need to make it into "2018-05-07" so that it is MySQL compatible, you can use:

```php
if (!empty($date)) {
  $timestamp = strtotime($date);
  if ($timestamp === FALSE) {
    $timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date));
  }
  $date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**For first Date**

```
$_firstDate = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($_yourDateString));
```

**For New Date**

```
$_newDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_yourDateString));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have format dd-mm-yyyy then in PHP it won't work as expected. In PHP document they have below guideline.

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

So, you just can't use as you wish. When your try to use dd/mm/yyyy format with this then it will remove FALSE. You can tweak with the following.

```
$date = "23/02/2013";
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
if ($timestamp === FALSE) {
  $timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date));
}
echo $timestamp; // prints 1361577600
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me to do something like:

$stringDate = "2022-02-24T17:15:00";
(if you only send the date "2022-02-24" it fills the time in 00:00:00).

$dateFormat = new DateTime($miStringDate);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I try all the above answers, but fail for me where in my case I built a function that get date string with the following format 'YYYY/mm/dd' . so i think much better to explode the string like that:

```
$old_date = explode('/', $coming_date_str);
```

`$new_data = $old_date[0].'-'.$old_date[1].'-'.$old_date[2];` // this to convert the string as all the above posts and complete

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($new_data));
$new_date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", new_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to accept dates using American ordering (month, date, year) for European style formats (using dash or period as day, month, year) ***while still accepting other formats***, you can extend the DateTime class:

```
/**
 * Quietly convert European format to American format
 *
 * Accepts m-d-Y, m-d-y, m.d.Y, m.d.y, Y-m-d, Y.m.d
 * as well as all other built-in formats
 * 
 */
class CustomDateTime extends DateTime 
{
  public function __construct(string $time="now", DateTimeZone $timezone = null) 
  {
    // convert m-d-y or m.d.y to m/d/y to avoid PHP parsing as d-m-Y (substr avoids microtime error)
    $time = str_replace(['-','.'], '/', substr($time, 0, 10)) . substr($time, 10 );

    parent::__construct($time, $timezone);
  }
}

// usage:
$date = new CustomDateTime('7-24-2019');
print $date->format('Y-m-d');

// => '2019-07-24'
```

Or, you can make a function to accept m-d-Y and output Y-m-d:

```
/**
 * Accept dates in various m, d, y formats and return as Y-m-d
 * 
 * Changes PHP's default behaviour for dates with dashes or dots.
 * Accepts:
 *   m-d-y, m-d-Y, Y-m-d,
 *   m.d.y, m.d.Y, Y.m.d,
 *   m/d/y, m/d/Y, Y/m/d,
 *   ... and all other formats natively supported 
 * 
 * Unsupported formats or invalid dates will generate an Exception
 * 
 * @see https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php PHP formats supported
 * @param  string $d various representations of date
 * @return string    Y-m-d or '----' for null or blank
 */
function asYmd($d) {
  if(is_null($d) || $d=='') { return '----'; }

  // convert m-d-y or m.d.y to m/d/y to avoid PHP parsing as d-m-Y
  $d = str_replace(['-','.'], '/', $d);

  return (new DateTime($d))->format('Y-m-d');
}

// usage:

<?= asYmd('7-24-2019') ?>

// or

<?php echo asYmd('7-24-2019'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the last day of the current month you can do it with the following code.

```php
$last_day_this_month  = date('F jS Y', strtotime(date('F t Y')));
```