# Verify valid date using PHP's DateTime class

Tags: php, datetime

Below is how I previously verified dates.  I also had my own functions to convert date formats, however, now am using PHP's DateTime class so no longer need them.  How should I best verify a valid date using DataTime? Please also let me know whether you think I should be using DataTime in the first place.  Thanks

PS.  I am using Object oriented style, and not Procedural style.

```
static public function verifyDate($date)
{
  //Given m/d/Y and returns date if valid, else NULL.
  $d=explode('/',$date);
  return ((isset($d[0])&&isset($d[1])&&isset($d[2]))?(checkdate($d[0],$d[1],$d[2])?$date:NULL):NULL);
}
```

Comment: It seems kind of odd to say that you're using OO-style, and then present a statically defined function.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
static public function verifyDate($date)
{
    return (DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date) !== false);
}
```

This outputs true/false. You could return `DateTime` object directly:

```
static public function verifyDate($date)
{
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date);
}
```

Then you get back a `DateTime` object or false on failure.

UPDATE:

Thanks to Elvis Ciotti who showed that createFromFormat accepts invalid dates like 45/45/2014.
More information on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10120725/1948627

I've extended the method with a strict check option:

```
static public function verifyDate($date, $strict = true)
{
    $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date);
    if ($strict) {
        $errors = DateTime::getLastErrors();
        if (!empty($errors['warning_count'])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $dateTime !== false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Redreggae, Looks like this will work.  If I didn't care about the original format but only that it is a valid date, would you recommend just creating a new DateTime($data), and using exceptions?

Comment: I have updated my answer...exceptions won't help, because the method doesn't throw an exception on failure only returns `false`.

Comment: Sorry didn't answer you question right. If you don't care about the date format, then shadyyx's solution is better.

Comment: I believe exceptions will work if all you care about is whether the date was of any acceptable format, but not if you were checking if it was in the m/d/Y format.

Comment: I think I didn't ask it right, but since I said "given m/d/Y", you answered it correct.  Sorry for the confusion, I wish I could answer them both correct.

Comment: careful
`DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2014-21-31')->format('d/m/Y')`
outputs `01/10/2015`, not `false`

Comment: @ElvisCiotti thanks for this information. I've made an update.

Comment: @bitWorking might I suggest that you add a `format` argument to the function, to allow for format strings to be passed to the Datetime function; and that the function itself return either the Datetime object created or `false`, to increase its utility?

Comment: Maybe i'm late with my comment but better late than never - `::createFromFormat('m/Y')` can return `true` on invalid date as `82/2017` **with strict**

Answer (score 16):

With DateTime you can make the shortest date&time validator for all formats.

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}

var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-28 12:12:12')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-30 12:12:12')); # false
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

Comment: This doesn't hold true for formats like: `!m/Y` or `d-m-Y|`. Additional parsing is necessary in such cases.

Answer (score 11):

You could check this resource: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php

The PHP codes states:

```
try {
    $date = new DateTime('asdfasdf');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors());
    // or
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't throw an exception if the string is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: The issue with this - not actually the code's, but PHP's fault - that from 24:00 to 24:59 time is accepted without error.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
  function is_valid_date($date,$format='dmY')
  {
    $f = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    $valid = DateTime::getLastErrors();         
    return ($valid['warning_count']==0 and $valid['error_count']==0);
  }
```

Comment: It's more concise and safe (check both counter: warning_count and error_count). I would just add a third condition (just in case): $f !== false.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to allow user input in (n) different, known, formats...including microtime. Here is an example with 3.

```
function validateDate($date)
{
    $formats = ['Y-m-d','Y-m-d H:i:s','Y-m-d H:i:s.u'];
    foreach($formats as $format) {
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
        if ($d && $d->format($format) == $date) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date[] = '20/11/2569';     
$date[] = 'lksdjflskdj'; 
$date[] = '11/21/1973 10:20:30';
$date[] = '21/11/1973 10:20:30';
$date[] = " ' or uid like '%admin%"; 
foreach($date as $dt)echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dt))."\n";
```

Output

```
1970-01-01 05:30:00
1970-01-01 05:30:00
1970-01-01 05:30:00
1973-11-21 10:20:30
1970-01-01 05:30:00
1970-01-01 05:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the combination of date_parse and checkdate works best and it is almost one-liner:

```
$date="2024-02-29";
$dp=date_parse("$date");

if (sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d",$dp['year'], $dp['month'], $dp['day'])===$date && checkdate($dp['month'], $dp['day'], $dp['year'])) {
    // format is OK and date is valid
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With the following an empty string like '' or 0 or '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is false

```
$valid = strtotime($date) > 0;
```

Comment: I know this comment is more than a decade old... Still, this is bascially a regex checker which doesn't cover months with less than 31 days such as '2000-11-31'.