# php check if valid date and time

Tags: php, date

I want to create a function, to check if `$date` is a valid date and time

```
function validateDate($date){
    $format = 'Y-m-d h:i A';// Eg : 2014-09-24 10:19 PM
    ....
}
```

I want to check the $date is valid, and it is in given format:

- If the statement is true {
       function should return corresponding time() of the date using  strtotime() or any other functions,,
  }
- Otherwise {
       `return false`
  }

You may suggest me to use `regex`. But I think it have limitation in the case of `feb`,`april`,`june`,`sep`,`nov` etc.

I found a code to check if the date is valid.

```
function validateDate($date){
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
    return $d && $d->format('Y-m-d') == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

But I didn't understood it's logic.

Comment: You found this one didn't you http://stackoverflow.com/a/19271434/ - I'm tempted to vote to close this as an exact duplicate. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504913/verify-valid-date-using-phps-datetime-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function validateDate($date) {
    $format = 'Y-m-d h:i A'; // Eg : 2014-09-24 10:19 PM
    $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);

    if ($dateTime instanceof DateTime && $dateTime->format('Y-m-d h:i A') == $date) {
        return $dateTime->getTimestamp();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 on line 4

Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 on line 6

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createfromformat() on line 4

Comment: Thankyou , I am 15 yr old.. Can you explain the different keywords, operators , functions used in the code above