# How to validate date format when one or more dates are returned

Tags: php, regex

I have a form that uses jquery datepicker. I have set it up to allow multiple date selections, it can return up to 4 dates or as few as 1. I am terrible at regex and the following works when the day is 2 digits(ie 10-31) but when the date is a single digit, with no leading zero it fails miserably. A little help with the regex please?

```
if(!empty($_POST['auction_date'])){
    $new_dates = explode('+',$_POST['auction_date']);
    foreach ($new_dates as $date){
        if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/", $date)){
            $errormsg[] = 'Date format is incorrect.';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Collect the dates with a simple regex like `\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b`, 2) use [datetime validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504913/verify-valid-date-using-phps-datetime-class) against each value found.

Comment: Add an optional sign `?` in front the zeroes. It would be `"/^[0-9]{4}-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/"`.

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! datetime validation was exactly what I needed, much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do that in 2 steps.

- Collect all the dates with a mere `'/\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b/'` regex.
- Use the [date validation described in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504913/verify-valid-date-using-phps-datetime-class)

A sample [PHP code](http://ideone.com/aChhjI) for this:

```
$s = "2015-12-23: started. 2017-02-29 ended";
preg_match_all('/\b(?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})\b/', $s, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($m as $dt)
{
    if (checkdate($dt["month"], $dt["day"], $dt["year"]) == true)
        echo "Valid date: " . $dt[0] . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo "Invalid date: " . $dt[0] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

`Valid date: 2015-12-23
Invalid date: 2017-02-29`

Comment: Does it work for you, or did you use any of the existing solutions I referenced to? Please let me know.

Comment: I used a datetime validation similar to the link you posted in your previous comment. The less I use preg match the better off I am as I can't get my head around it well enough to troubleshoot it if I ever run into a problem.

Comment: Actually the regex is basic. I just do not want to post identical solutions. Please consider accepting the answer since it worked for you.