# How can I parse a date from a text file?

Tags: php

I am parsing a date from a text file. Here my text file:

```
#Tue Jul 15 15:40:44 CEST 2015
```

This is how I am parsing it:

```
foreach ($linesArray AS $line) {
    if (strlen($line) && $line[0] == '#') {
       $date = strtotime(substr($line, 1));
       $strDate = date("y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
    }
```

But I get a different date as a result:

```
echo $strDate;
```

15-07-21 14:40:44

Comment: [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: @Jarla Er, my bad. Nevermind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php DateTime createFromFormat functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120643/php-datetime-createfromformat-functionality)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to always (mostly) specify what format are you parsing the date from. Basically, you need to build a string that works with your date format. All of the possible format parameter strings can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

This should work for your date formatting:

```
$date = "Tue Jul 15 15:40:44 CEST 2015";
$formatted = DateTime::createFromFormat('* M d H:i:s T Y',$date);
var_dump($formatted->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, this is working with your date, but not with mine. When I make your date `var_dump($date)` I get this result `string(29) "Tue Jul 15 15:40:44 CEST 2015"`, but my date looks like this: `string(30) "Tue Jul 15 15:40:44 CEST 2015 "` Why is my date not working?

Comment: So, it's the same date just with a space in the end? Use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove spaces from both sides. I'm not sure how your input is different to mine since I just copied the `$date` from your code.

Comment: thank you, trim worked, but the var_dump result of your code is still string(19) "2015-07-21 15:40:44"  From where comes the `21`?

Comment: I tried your code on an empty page and the result is `string(19) "2015-07-21 15:40:44"`

Comment: I've fixed the format to `'* M d H:i:s T Y'`. We don't actually want to parse the day name since it messes things up. Should work now.