# What create_from_format to use for timestamps in php

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I am working on a PHP file were I am pulling in timestamps from a database that come out as

```
Tue Sep 22 16:11:12 EDT 2015
Mon Nov 16 07:42:31 EST 2015
```

I was wondering how to convert dates of this format into unix time format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a date from a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650654/how-can-i-parse-a-date-from-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.datetime.php) object

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('Tue Sep 22 16:11:12 EDT 2015');

echo $dateTime->getTimestamp();
```

The result would be `1442952672`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the PHP manual for [`\DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) or [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), you will find tables of codes accepted by `\DateTime::createFromFormat()`. Looking at them you will see that you need the following:-

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s T Y', 'Tue Sep 22 16:11:12 EDT 2015');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/72qX0).

The 'd' in the format string may need to be a 'j' if day numbers < 10 are single digit.