# dd/mm/yyyy format date validation in yii2

Tags: regex, validation, date, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I would like to validate date field to accept only `(dd/mm/yyyy)` format, for example

```
(14/11/1993)
```

In addition if the month is February it should not accept day 30 and 31. Please help any one, I've already tried with the pattern below but it's not working in Yii 2. It shows error in `RegularExpressionValidator.php`

```
[
    ['dateofbirth'], 
    'match', 
    'pattern' => '/^((([1-2][0-9])|([1-9]))/([2])/[0-9]{4})|((([1-2][0-9])|([1-9])|(3[0-1]))/((1[0-2])|([3-9])|([1]))/[0-9]{4})$/', 
    'message' =>'Invalid date'
],
```

Comment: you want to put validation through rules in model right?

Comment: yes i want validation in rules@jigar

Comment: wait let me prepare it

Comment: thank u for spend your time

Comment: I think SiZE's answer is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try**

> (/^((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(/)(0[13578]|1[02]))|((0[1-9]|[12][0-9])(/)(02))|((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0])(/)(0[469]|11))(/)\d{4}$/)

**or**

> (^((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(/)(0[13578]|1[02]))|((0[1-9]|[12][0-9])(/)(02))|((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0])(/)(0[469]|11))(/)\d{4}$)

Comment: i change your regex like that it's working /^((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02]))|((0[1-9]|[12][0-9])\/(02))|((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0])\/(0[469]|11))\/\d{4}$/

Answer (score 3):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['dateofbirth', 'date', 'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy'],
    ];
}
```

Another way was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120643/php-datetime-createfromformat-functionality/10120725#10120725).

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['dateofbirth', 'validateDateOfBirth'],
    ];
}

public function validateDateOfBirth($attribute)
{
    $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $this->$attribute);
    $errors = DateTime::getLastErrors();
    if (!empty($errors['warning_count'])) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Invalid date');
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i already try this type of custom validation,it's validate after posing,at the time the page will refresh so only i need pattern,anyway thank u for your time.

Answer (score 0):

That one worked for me fine

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['dateofbirth', 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d'];
    ];
}
```

Here is more info on that [YII2 DateValidator docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-datevalidator.html#$format-detail)