# Why do strtotime() and date() return 1969-31-12?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have this code:

```
$endDate='02-20-2014'; //Just updated this
echo date('Y-d-m',strtotime($endDate));
```

Why does `strtotime()` keeps giving me `1969-31-12`?

My goal is to get: `2014-02-20`

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/1EEBIV (well, besides your formatting params are incorrect)

Comment: Reading the documentation for `strtotime`, it's obvious that a) you are using a PHP version earlier than 5.1.0, b) `strtotime` errors out, c) this causes it to return -1 and thus d) you get the timestamp for 1969-31-12 23:59:59. So, start by upgrading your PHP to a version that is not straight out of the middle ages. Perhaps that will fix your problem by itself.

Answer (score 2):

**The root problem**

[PHP supported date formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) do not include the input date format you're using, `'02-20-2014'` or `mm-DD-YY`

**Why you are getting `1969-31-12`**

Since your input format is wrong, `strtotime()` fails. In PHP 5.1 and above, `strtotime()` would have returned `false` in this case and the `date()` call would have evaluated to `1970-01-01` (i.e [the day of the UNIX epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).

However, in your case `strtotime()` seems to return `-1` on failure instead. This indicates you're using an outdated version of PHP ([5.0.x or less](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration51.datetime.php)). It also causes the `date()` call to return `1969-31-12` (i.e minus one second of [the UNIX epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time))

**The solution**

Change your input date format to any of the [PHP supported date formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). In addition, in order to get the output date format you indicate, `2014-02-20` or `YY-mm-dd`, you should adjust the `format` argument of the `date()` function in accordance from `Y-d-m` to `Y-m-d`.

For example:

```
$endDate='2014-20-02';
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($endDate));
```

**Side note about the PHP version**

If possible, it's highly recommended that you migrate your system from the outdated PHP 5.0.x version to the latest versions. You should be careful to check [the change logs of each version migration ever since](http://www.php.net/manual/en/appendices.php) to make sure you're not breaking any exiting code.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this and thought I should add a correction and additional information:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.  (source:
>   [Converting string to Date and DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime))

If using `strtotime`  then  02-20-2014 != 02/20/2014

02-20-2014 will fail as there is no 20th month

02/20/2014 is 20th February

If you use the a year first format as detailed above eg

```
$endDate='2014-20-02';
```

then the middle pair of numbers is ***always*** a month so this date is invalid whether your dates are American or European.

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($endDate));
```

and

```
echo date('Y-d-m',strtotime($endDate));
```

will both fail as the first parameter passed to date is the output format and `strtotime` will already have failed leading to a returned date of "1969-12-31"