# How to change time format from M-d-Y to Y-M-d in php?

Tags: php, date

I am taking the input in M-d-Y format from calender but I want to convert it into Y-m-d when it store in the database. What method can I use?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$date="05-25-2014";
print(date("y-m-d",strtotime($date)));
```

Comment: Doing this giving me this error:                  Undefined index: 70-01-01 in D:\xampp\htdocs\my bus ticket reservation system\myticket.php on line 84

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. `strtotime` is your friend.

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('Dec-02-2014'));
```

or mysql [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function, but mysql stores dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Answer (score -1):

I think it better to do it in Mysql itself. When we have so many function.  Like below:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Jan-31-2014', '%b-%d-%Y');
```

You can use it for insert query like below:

```
Insert into tableName `date` = STR_TO_DATE(InputVal, '%b-%d-%Y');
```

For more info:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score -2):

use the `date()` and `strtotime()` like:

```
 $var = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($timestring))
```

[Converting string to Date and DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime)

copy from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6239010/2478144

> Make not that there is a difference between using forward slash / and hyphen - in the strtotime function. to quote from php.net

Comment: Answer giving is 70-01-01