# PHP Date Conversion YYMMDD to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-conversion

Hi I am struggling with converting a string:

```
$file = '150220';
```

into a mysql date format.

I have tried this

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($file));
```

But it returns the following 2015-02-24 (24 being today's date)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime  see the one with most votes :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

So you can use this:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymd', $file);
$newDate = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` is a wonderful function. It works when you provide YYYY-MM-DD format but not with YY-MM-DD.

EDIT: As said in comments, you have to "turn the string into a valid ISO8601 Notations format by prepending '20' - this is understood by strtotime as specified in the docs "

This will work for the next 85 years with 64 bits systems (Until 2038 on 32 bit systems)

```
$file = '150220';
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("20$file"));
```

You have to be careful with strtotime because it returns false on error which will make `date` used today's date.

EDIT: if you want to -1 : first, this code works and it explains why op's code does not work, then consider using the "Add comment" button. Thanks.

Comment: 150220 its a date in format of ymd . so how strtotime gonna know that?

Comment: strtotime is a wonderful function. It works when you provide YYYY-MM-DD format but not with YY-MM-DD.

Comment: so care to explain why is there 20 before $file? and does this code work for 150324 too? does it really answers what op asked for?

Comment: 20th february of 2015 is "20150220" in YYYY-MM-DD format, you have to put the century in order for it to work

Comment: Mark could you explain what you are saying?

Comment: @Adam - he's referring to the fact that 32 bit dates can't go past 2038 - see second note on [PHP strtotime documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).  You should explain that you're turning the string into a valid ISO8601 Notations format by prepending '20' - this is understood by strtotime as specified in the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: Yes thanks,  i will modify my answer as you suggest. People don't seem to understand such thing.