# Symfony 2 PHP comparing dates issues

Tags: php, symfony, date

using php 5.5.9 . I have Tranche Entity, and it has a date attribute. What I want is to get number of rows matching a criteria; having date gt/lt current date ,so I created a twig extension, this is my code:
following this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime)

```
public function e()
{
    $criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();
    $date=date('Y-m-d');
    $criteria->where($criteria->expr()->lt('date',$date));
    $result=$this->em->getRepository('OCUserBundle:Tranche')->matching($criteria);
    return count($result);
}
```

My problem is that I can't compare dates no matter what I tried.

This is the error:

DateType.php line 53: Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

I've searched a lot and tried many suggestions, not working and I'm stuck. What's happening and thank you in advance.

Comment: even if you try $date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($timestamp))?;

Comment: did what you suggested, same error.

Comment: I can't even tell from where the error comes.

Comment: where do you get your date? You are converting it two times.

Comment: `$criteria->where($criteria->expr()->lt('date', new \DateTime()));`

Comment: Question and code updated. same error.@aldrin27

Comment: Thanks, I don't why it didn't came to my mind! I have been sitting for 5 hours straight on my lap. Thank you @Qoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved as @Qoop said. It should be :

```
$criteria->where($criteria->expr()->lt('date', new \DateTime()));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function e() {
 $criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();
 $d=date('Y-m-d'); // i think your error is here
 $timestamp = strtotime($d); //here
 $date=date('Y-m-d',$timestamp); //and here

 $d = //place here where the date is coming from
 $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d)); //formatter of date
 $criteria->where($criteria->expr()->lt('date',$date));
 $result=$this->em->getRepository('OCUserBundle:Tranche')->matching($criteria);
 return count($result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts aldrin27. Qoop answered my question.

Comment: No problem @AbdelazizDabebi. I realized that you want to get the current time.