# PHP date_format(): How to format date from string value

Tags: php, date-format

**I have a bit of PHP code:**

```
$exd = date_create('01 Dec, 2015');
$exd = date_format($exd, 'Y-m-d');
echo $exd;
```

Which is used for formatting the date. The expected output would be `2015-12-01` but it returns `2016-12-01`. What am i missing?

Comment: The date inside `date_create()` seems to be in text format.

Comment: you first need string to time convert..you can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `createFromFormat` method first, provide the input format:

```
$exd = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M, Y', '01 Dec, 2015');
// arguments (<format of the input>, <the input itself>)
$exd = date_format($exd, 'Y-m-d'); // then choose whatever format you like
echo $exd;
```

Answer (score 4):

The `date_create()` function accepts only the parameter [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php), This function is also and alias function of `DateTime::__construct()`

check the function `date_create_from_format()` its also a alias function of DateTime::createFromFormat(). Refer [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php)

```
$exd = date_create_from_format('j M, Y', '01 Dec, 2015');
//$exd = date_create('01 Dec, 2015');
$exd = date_format($exd, 'Y-m-d');
echo $exd;
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be a date function call simply. Use stringtotime for exact/precise date/time value

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("01 Dec 2015"))
```

When you run this code the out put will show

```
2015-12-01
```

this is because of the comma in the string which terminates the date string in the compiler. If you specify exactly the timezone (like 
`$timezone = 'America/New_York`) . parameter you can show precise time as well.

Answer (score -2):

i got the solution of your bug
that is **date_format(datae_variable,date_format);**

```
<?php
     $exd = date_create('01 Dec, 2015');
     $exd1 = date_format($exd,"Y-m-d");//here you make mistake
     echo $exd1;
?>
```

Comment: Good try... But please confirm the results before try. You can use http://phpfiddle.org/ for debugging and checking the results.

Comment: this code is also run phpfiddle.org check that first

Comment: Please check the result. Expected would be `2015-12-01` but result was `2016-12-01`

Comment: oooh am sorry i just check the format sorry ! r u from where? please