# date() which echo's correct date and time format, but doesn't store it correctly in database

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have the following snippet of code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
if (!isset($_POST['secret']) && $post_msg != "" ) { // checkbox unchecked processing...
    // Checkbox is selected
    $date_of_msg= date('l jS F Y h:i');
    $msg_sent_by  = $username;
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO user_thoughts VALUES ('','$post_msg','$date_of_msg','','' ,'$attach_name','$msg_sent_by','yes')";
    $run_query = mysqli_query($connect, $insert_query) or die(mysqli_error());
}
```

When I echo `$date_of_msg`, the date and time will print out as expected, but when the following `INSERT` query above is ran, the field in the db will store `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

The field which will store `$date_of_msg` is called `post_details` and is of type `datetime`. I am aware that there is a function called `date_to_str` and have seem questions related to it, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime) one. But the answers in that question are converting manually inputted dates, whereas I want to get the time when a user makes a post. I think the solution is to use the `date_to_str` function when inserting the `$date_of_msg` variable? But I am unable to understand how it works?

Comment: `l jS F Y h:i` is not mysql's datetime format. Why not use `now()`?

Comment: MySQL expects dates to be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

Comment: What is the format of your destination column? If it is DATE format then you need to change your input layout as detailed by the comments above. Also your `MySQLi_error()` needs to contain the `$connect` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
date('l jS F Y h:i');
```

is sending a result like:

> Wednesday 2nd March 2016 10:00

so you are getting that value `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as a mismatch of datetime

Change it to:

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

or format the date to something you need using this doc. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because your web server (apache im guessing) configuration is different than your mysql config.

So that's why you're experiencing some confusion.

There are a few ways to go about this, but it will require you to choose a format and run with it.

1. When inserting the record to mysql, tell it what format you want to use.

   $query_manual = "INSERT INTO dateplayground (dp_name, dp_datetime)
   VALUES ('DATETIME: Manual DateTime', '1776-7-4 04:13:54')";
2. Research mysql and apache date time configurations and fix both of them so they have the same exact date time format.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql datetime field, you can insert only the date time of the format `Y:m:d H:i:s`

Please use the datetime with the same format

```
$date_of_msg = date('Y:m:d H:i:s');
```