# Laravel Query using yyyy-mm--dd value on datetime column

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have written the following query using the laravel query builder. I am trying to get the count of fields in a column for a userID, activityID, and a date. It is the date field input that is causing the issue. I want to be able to return all the fields that have the same date as the date value I pass in. Below is my code.

```
$points = DB:: table("users_has_activities")
-> where("activitiesID", "=", $this->activityID)
-> where("usersID", "=", $userID)
-> where("time", "=", $date)
-> count();
```

$date will be a value like "2016-04-10", and the field in my table will have values like '2016-04-10 21:01:27'. I need to be able to get all the fields where the day of the date value matches the day of the datetime value in the table.

Comment: What is the MySQL type of the `time` column?

Comment: the type is datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [whereDay()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/3946/files) method to get the `DATE` from `DATETIME` type:

```
$points = DB:: table("users_has_activities")
-> where("activitiesID", "=", $this->activityID)
-> where("usersID", "=", $userID)
-> whereDay("time", "=", $date)
-> count();
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way to make it work if $date is a string I have tried using strtotime but that doesn't work

Comment: check @Matthew's answer  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime/6239199#6239199)

Comment: I solved it like this passing in $newDate instead of date.                $originalDate = $date;
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is a `whereBetween` as it'll be able to use database indexes and doesn't need a calculation for each row in the DB:

```
$points = DB:: table("users_has_activities")
-> where("activitiesID", "=", $this->activityID)
-> where("usersID", "=", $userID)
-> whereBetween("time", '2016-04-12 00:00:00', '2016-04-12 23:59:59')
-> count();
```

Laravel's bundled Carbon can be handy for generating these dates. If your column is flagged as a date (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) they'll be carbon objects already:

```
$start = $date->copy()->startOfDay();
$end = $date->copy()->endOfDay();
```