# Store date directly in PHP variable

Tags: php, date

I want to store a specific date in a variable. If stored like `$x="01/01/2016"` it is acting as a string  from which I cannot extract a part, like from `getdate()` year, month, day of the month, etc.

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime

Comment: try `echo date('y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $x )));`

Answer (score 5):

Use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2016/01/01');
```

To get only parts of the date you can use the `format` method:

```
echo $dateTime->format('Y'); // it will display 2016
```

If you need to create it from the format you wrote in the question, then you can use the factory method `createFromFormat`:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/01/2016');
echo $dateTime->format('Y/m/d');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me

```
 $date = '20/May/2015:14:00:01';
    $dateInfo = date_parse_from_format('d/M/Y:H:i:s', $date);
    $unixTimestamp = mktime(
        $dateInfo['hour'], $dateInfo['minute'], $dateInfo['second'],
        $dateInfo['month'], $dateInfo['day'], $dateInfo['year'],
        $dateInfo['is_dst']
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$myDate = new DateTime('01/01/2016');` to declare date. To get year, month and date from the specified date, use `echo $myDate->format('d m Y');`

Change the format based on your need. To know more about date format [refer](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)