# Saving a datepicker value to database in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have this input in my form... I need to store the date picked from it, but I get a null value when I submit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
   });
</script>

<input type="text" required="" placeholder="When are You Coming Back" name="datepicker2"  id="datepicker2" value="" name="datepicker2" class="txt">
```

am I missing something?? when I submit I don't get any values in the database, I am using `laravel5`

```
class LeaveController extends Controller
{
     public function ApplyLeave(Request $request)
    {

        Auth::user()->sent()->create([
            'tel'       => $request->tel,
            'email'    => $request->email,
            'start' => $request->datepicker,
            'end'       => $request->datepicker1,
            'supervisor'    => $request->supervisor,
            'department' => $request->department,
            'name'    => $request->name,
            'adress' => $request->adress,
        ]);   
        return view('home');
   }
```

Comment: Where is the relevant code from your controller?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy ihave edited the question with my controlller

Comment: your input name is datepicker2 but in your request object you calling without a number and with number 1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Parsing dates should work:

```
'start' => Carbon::parse($request->datepicker),
'end' => Carbon::parse($request->datepicker1),
```

Also, it's a good idea to put `start` and `end` to the [`$dates`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) array.

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Carbon' not found error

Comment: Either import it at the top like this `use Carbon\Carbon` or call it like this: `\Carbon\Carbon::parse(...)`

Comment: OOps   DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (dfg) at position 0 (d): The timezone could not be found in the database..sorry for my poor debuging skills though

Comment: As @JayminPanchal answered, you'll need to convert the datepicker output format to `Y-m-d` format. There's plenty of ways to do it (server, client). A good start would be telling us what format is your datepicker outputting.

Comment: how do i get that?? how do i print the output?

Comment: 01/06/2017 after i pick a date it looks like this

Comment: @SirGeorge I've just tried and `Carbon::parse('01/06/2017')` parses this date to `2017-01-06`.

Comment: there is no error now, but my start and end columns are still empty? its like i dint even pick a date

Comment: if i check my columns in the db, its written NULL my datatype in the db is "date"

Comment: i got it thanks guys .. i appreciate stack overflow very mmuch..thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your date to the format the DB accept like `Y-m-d` i.e. `2017-01-19`.

Try to convert it before storing in DB

like,

```
public function ApplyLeave(Request $request){

    Auth::user()->sent()->create([
        'tel'       => $request->tel,
        'email'    => $request->email,
        'start' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->datepicker)),
        'end'       => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->datepicker1)),
        'supervisor'    => $request->supervisor,
        'department' => $request->department,
        'name'    => $request->name,
        'adress' => $request->adress,
    ]);   
    return view('home');
}
```

Comment: still empty..is it because i set the default value to null??

Comment: just print the value of `$request->datepicker` `$request->datepicker1` and post it so that we can help you more

Answer (score 1):

Use strtotime() on your first date then date('Y-m-d') to convert it back:

```
$time = strtotime('10/16/2003');

$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);

echo $newformat;
```

// 2003-10-16

[Converting string to Date and DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime/6239010#6239010)