# How to query a date table when date is string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Using the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime), I wanted to return all objects based on `created_at`.

```
$projects = [ {id => 1,..., 'created_at' => "2017-05-15 14:46:32",...}, ]

$time = strtotime('2017-05-15'); // format issue?

$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time); // "2017-05-15"

$projects = $user->projects->where('created_at', $newformat);
```

Im getting back an empty array for `$projects`, same in `tinker`. Yes, eloquent is perfect. Am I going it the right way?

Since I am here, I need to query two dates ie `$from` and `$to` with `whereBetween`:

```
$projects = $user->projects->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->toArray();
```

I cant remember where I saw `whereBetween` from but that give me the error:
`$from` and `$to` would be similar to `$newformat`.

> Method whereBetween does not exist.

Comment: `$projects = $user->projects->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();` Did you try this one?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn i, yes, i have tried that but keep getting `Method whereBetween does not exist.` Do i need to add that to my model? Sorry, Im new to laravel. I have a read. thanks

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn That won't work; `$user->projects` is a `Collection` not a `QueryBuilder`. `Collection`s don't have a `whereBetween` method.

Comment: @Sylar Yes please try to `$projects = $user->projects()->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();`

Comment: @TimLewis Yes sir. My mistake. It's should be `projects()` not `projects`

Comment: Ok but my array is empty. If I include the time, I get what I expected. How to query with just the date for `created_at`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `projects` as a method, not a property:

```
$projects = $user->projects()->where('created_at', $newformat)->get();
```

Trying to access `$user->projects` without the `()` will return a `Collection`, which doesn't have the `whereBetween` method. You would have to use:

```
$user->projects()->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();
```

In that instance. Note that `Collections` have a `where` method, but it doesn't work the same was as `Eloquent`'s.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-where

If you want to query dates, I find it best to use `whereRaw()`:

```
$user->project()->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'");
```

And if only querying a single date:

```
$user->project()->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y-%m-%d') = '".$newFormat."'");
```

I should also add that there is a `whereDate()` clause available as a shorthand to the above:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses

```
$user->projects()->whereDate("created_at", $newFormat)
```

There's also `whereYear()`, `whereMonth()` and `whereDay()`, which could be chained to search for a specific date.

Comment: Hi. But in tinker `App\Project::where(...)` is still the same

Comment: Might be an issue with your query then. `created_at` has Hours, Minutes and Seconds on it, so `->where("created_at", $newFormat)` would fail.

Comment: Correct. Thats my issue now

Comment: Im now getting `syntax error, unexpected '"'"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)`

Comment: Woops, missed a `.` here `AND '".$to"'"` Should be `AND '".$to."'"`

Comment: What this means: `Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: ` timestamp without time zone`

Comment: Oh you're probably not using `MySQL` are you? Error suggests you're using `postgresql`, which likely doesn't have a `DATE_FORMAT()` method. You'll have to do some debugging there; never used `postgresql`

Comment: No lol sorry. posgresql but it needs to be compatible and on local machines, I use posgresql and other dev,...mysql

Comment: No worries; I made the assumption, so that was my bad. Unfortunately, I have no experience with `postgresql`, so I won't be much help. See if you can google how to query dates in postgres, or see if there's any SO questions on the subject. I'd consider this question closed though; solution to your initial question is there, but created another separate issue.

Comment: No worries. I have tried on another machine and it do works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time).'%'; // "2017-05-15"

$projects = $user->projects()->where('created_at', 'like', $newformat);
```