# Update error when adding 2 digit integer mysql

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm getting an error on a mySql insert when i go to insert a double digit integer. When inserting a single digit integer value everything works fine, but for the double digit e.g 18, I get a foreign key constraint error (below) and the column will default to 1.

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`deposit_guard`.`tenants`, CONSTRAINT `tenants_to_properties` FOREIGN KEY (`listing_id`) REFERENCES `properties` (`property_id`))

Insert Code:

```
session_start();
require_once('../dbconnect.php');
if(isset($_POST["t_name"]))
/* multiline add to database and changed for my purposes http://www.webslesson.info/2017/03/multiple-inline-insert-data-using-ajax-jquery-php.html */
{
$t_name = $_POST["t_name"];
$t_email = $_POST["t_email"];
$t_deposit = $_POST["t_deposit"];
$t_start = $_POST["t_start"];
$t_duration = $_POST["t_duration"];
$prop_id = $_POST["prop_id"];
$query = '';
for($count = 0; $count<count($t_name); $count++)
{
$t_name_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $t_name[$count]);
$t_email_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $t_email[$count]);
$t_deposit_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $t_deposit[$count]);
/* converting string to date: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime */
$t_duration_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $t_duration[$count]);
$t_start_clean = date("y-m-d", strtotime($t_start[$count]));
$t_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" .$t_duration_clean[$count] ."months", strtotime($t_start_clean)));
$prop_id_clean = $prop_id[0];
if($prop_id_clean != '' && $t_name_clean != '' && $t_email_clean != '' && $t_deposit_clean != '' && $t_start_clean != ''  && $prop_id_clean != ''  && $t_duration_clean != '' && $t_end != '')
{
$query .= '
INSERT INTO tenants(listing_id, name, email, deposit_amount, s_date, duration, e_date) 
VALUES("'.$prop_id_clean.'","'.$t_name_clean.'", "'.$t_email_clean.'", "'.$t_deposit_clean.'", "'.$t_start_clean.'" , "'.$t_duration_clean.'" , "'.$t_end.'"); 
';
}
}
if($query != '')
{
if(mysqli_multi_query($conn, $query))
{
echo 'Tenant added';
}
else
{
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn), $prop_id_clean;
}
}
else
{
echo 'All Fields are Required';
}
}
?>
```

Any ideas why this could be happening? I can add code if necessary, i'm using PHP if that is of any benefit.
Thanks!

PASTEBIN: https://pastebin.com/k6FZVBy6

Comment: Edit your question putting the `insert` code...

Comment: I would imagine that it's because the single digit integer you're inserting happens to be an acceptable value in the other table to which the foreign key relates. Check the "properties" table and see what the available values of "property_id" are. You'll probably find there is no 18 in there.

Comment: @Dalton just edited now!

Comment: @Loki there is an 18 in there, i checked the dB and I wouldn't be able to add it through the application otherwise

Comment: Are you sure this is right: `$prop_id_clean = $prop_id[0];` ? Should it not be `$prop_id_clean = $prop_id[$count];`?

Comment: Also, you have to check if the `$prop_id` is valid in the `properties` table (`property_id`)...

Comment: @Dalton i created a single number array for my ajax call in the other page ad the prop_id stays the same but the other array values change. I should change the name from $prop_id_clean to something more relevant by right. The prop_id has to be valid, it wouldn't show otherwise

Comment: If I go into phpMyAdmin, tenants table and insert i can select 18 as a value also

Answer (score 0):

- For both the foreign key and the primary key data type and size must
  be same for both the table. If the size or data type is different
  then it will throw an error.
- For your case the size of the integer is different , In primary table the size 
  is 11 byte and in secondary table the size is 4 byte.