# Parse custom date and time by user through postman

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen, lumen-5.4

I wanted to pass the custom data through postman but the problem is how do I parse date and time in a field at time? Initially I tried strtotime function but I wanted it along with the date. This is my post API:

```
$post =  Auth::user()->posts()->create([
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'post_id' => rand(),
                'title' => $request->title,
                'time' => strtotime($request->time),
            ]);
```

Comment: How does your data look like? Please add an example.

Comment: Please show us what is in your `$request->time` field

Comment: i passed time as 22-04-19 12:00:01  through postman

Comment: And what do you want in the `'time'` field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to Date and DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option

```
$in = '22-04-19 12:00:01';

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($in));
```

RESULT

```
2022-04-19 12:00:01
```

A slightly more reliable method

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y-m-d H:i:s', $in);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

RESULT

```
2022-04-19 12:00:01
```