# Laravel - How to convert VARCHAR to TIMESTAMP or DATETIME using RAW DB

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.8 to run a query, from a table given to me. I observed that one of the fields (created_at) is varchar instead of timestamp or datetime. 
Note that I can not alter the table in my case.

```php
$winners = DB::table('winner')
    ->select('msisdn', 'created_at')               
    ->orderByRaw('created_at DESC')
    ->get();
```

I am using DB Raw.

From my query, please how do I convert, `created_at` (varchar) to timestamp or datetime.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to Date and DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime)

Comment: Its not a duplicate, OP is asking how to get the field from Db directly converted into timestamp, not how do you convert a normal date string in PHP to timestamp, its different

Answer (score 2):

Using the `CAST` function of SQL as below

```php
$winners = DB::table('winner')
    ->select( 'msisdn', DB::raw('CAST(created_at AS DATETIME)') )               
    ->orderByRaw('created_at DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: This will only cast to DATE and loose the time part

Comment: Did not tested this, but will this return a PHP \DateTime?

Comment: Yes. It will. Feel free to try it out and let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: I think `DB::raw('DATETIME(created_at)')` is acceptable too.

Comment: Question asked using `raw DB`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon, which is already included as a dependency of Laravel:
[Carbon documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation)

```php
$winners->map(static function($winner){
    $winner['created_at'] = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($winner['created_at']);

    return $winner;
});
```

But please notice that Carbon::parse() may not be the best option here, passing a valid format is better `Carbon::createFromFormat(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to do so is to use [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

And inside your `Winner` model apply the accessor as:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date);
}
```

This way you dont need to loop through your results after fetching it. Also you might be fetching winners in more than one controller, this way the created_at will always come as timestamp so you dont need to worry about it and write some code every time after fetching winners.

I thought it was obvious but since I got a negative vote for it. Please note to use model after defining the accessor like so:

```
$winners = \App\Winner::select('msisdn', 'created_at')               
    ->orderByRaw('created_at DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: He ist using DB Raw which means he will get an stdClass instance and not a Winner model instance

Comment: @JoaquinMarcher, i thought it was obvious, mentioned it in the answer now