# Converting string of numbers to date in PHP

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to convert a string of numbers I am pulling from a db that looks like this '010219', representing January 2, 2019. I cannot find a way to convert this into 2019-01-02 using php, I just keep getting today's date from the functions I am trying.

Needs to be accomplished with no separators in original string.

Comment: Please share the functions that you are trying.

Comment: Take a look at [`date_create_from_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: I've tried a whole slew of different combinations, the problem seems to be with there being no symbols separating the numbers in the string I'm pulling from the db so the functions don't know what to do with it

Comment: Not a duplicate because I have no separators in the strings I'm trying to convert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to accomplish this, however the most concise is probably to use `date_create_from_format`.

An example is here:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('dmy', '010219');
```

This will output a Date as so:

```
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');

Outputs: 2019-02-01
```

The `date_create_from_format` function accepts a parameter that defines the format of the date.  In this case, the format is `dmy` which means:

```
d - Day of month as two-digit number (01-31)
m - Month of year as two-digit number (01-12)
y - Year as two-digit number
```

The documentation for `date_create_from_format` is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

have you tried something like this?

```
<?php
$str="010219";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', $str);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); //2019-02-01
```

Answer (score 0):

$time = strtotime('10/16/2003');

$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);

echo $newformat;
// 2003-10-16

Please see source: [Converting string to Date and DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

split and concatenate with preg_replace

```
$newformat = preg_replace("/^(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)$/","20$3-$1-$2","010219");
```