# How to split date and time from a string like 8/29/2011 1:00 PM in laravel

Tags: laravel

in my blade there is a DateTime picker which selects in `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM` format. and i need to extract this to `date = 8/29/2011` and  `time = 13:00` .
how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string to Date and DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as below.

```
$stringdate = "8/29/2011 1:00 PM";
$timestemp = strtotime($stringdate);
$date = date('Y-m-d', $timestemp);
$time = date('H:i:s',$timestemp);

echo $date;

echo $time;
```

check [example](https://3v4l.org/n5LIm)

**Edit:-** as you want this format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm`

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime("8/29/2011 1:00 PM"));
echo $datetime; //output "2011-08-29 13:00";
```

Comment: but i want to insert this date and time to a single field in db . so i want to merge it in this format 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm .

Comment: ive  assigned the date to a variable $input. then  i did $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i', "$input"); but it shows error

Comment: What error are you getting? use `$input` not `"$input"`. so now your code like be `$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i', $input);`

Comment: make sure that `$input` contain date?

Comment: message: "A non well formed numeric value encountered", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "/var/www/html/bms/app/Http/Controllers/bookSpaceController.php"
line: 44
message: "A non well formed numeric value encountered"
trace: [{function: "handleError", class: "Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions", type: "->"},…]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204385/discussion-between-aljin-abraham-and-dilip-hirapara).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204465/discussion-between-blonde-addicted-brunet-and-dilip-hirapara).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
@php
    $input  = '2017-06-27 12:58:20';
    $format1 = 'Y-m-d';
    $format2 = 'H:i:s';
    $date = Carbon\Carbon::parse($input)->format($format1);
    $time = Carbon\Carbon::parse($input)->format($format2);
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple just try it

```
$date="8/29/2011 1:00 PM"; // date that get from view (blade page)

$createTimestamp = new DateTime($date); // create timestamp object from string

$date = $createTimestamp->format('m/d/Y'); // get date

$time = $createTimestamp->format('H:i:s A'); // get time with AM/PM format

return "date: ".$date." time: ".$time; // return your result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Use Carbon;

$dateAndTime=Carbon::parse('8/29/2011 1:00 PM');
$date=$dateAndTime->format('d-m-Y');// 29-8-2011
$time=$dateAndTime->format('H:i:s');// 1:00
$time=$dateAndTime->format('H:i:s A');// 1:00 AM/PM
```

Refer this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon) to understand more about Carbon.