# PHP Date Convert with slashes

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am having difficulty converting a date string passed via JSON into a PHP formatted date which I can use in date calculations and store in DATETIME format in MySQL.

```
$passedTime = "30/3/2020 17:7:23:847";
```

I'm looking to convert to the following format:

```
$convertedPassedTime = "2020-3-30 17:07:23";
```

I have tried several different combinations of 'DateTime::createFromFormat' but keep coming across errors. I cannot change the format of the incoming data as it comes from an old RFID reader device.

Comment: can you show your best attempt please?

Comment: The problem in single digit minutes. It is not matched any standard, So you need find how to change `"30/3/2020 17:7:23:847" >> "30/3/2020 17:07:23:847"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string to Date and DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime)

Comment: Please look is this make sense: https://phpize.online/?phpses=64e63bc595b85bb11ec8a347daa45dca&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is most likely a better solution than this, but as quick workaround this works:

```
$passedDate = "30/3/2020 17:7:23:847";
$explodedDateTime = explode(" ", $passedDate);
$explodedDate = explode("/", $explodedDateTime[0]);
$explodedTime = explode(":", $explodedDateTime[1]);

$formattedDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($explodedDate[2]."-".$explodedDate[1]."-".$explodedDate[0]." ".$explodedTime[0].":".$explodedTime[1].":".$explodedTime[2]));
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, there was a slight indexing error on the $explodedTime array. The array index was 0,1 and 2, not 2, 1, 0. See below.

`$formattedDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($explodedDate[2]."-".$explodedDate[1]."-".$explodedDate[0]." ".$explodedTime[0].":".$explodedTime[1].":".$explodedTime[2]));`

Comment: Oh yeah that would be the case, I accidentally did the indexes backwards on the times, thanks. Still glad it’s worked though. I’ll edit my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

You can also chose to make it compatible with the [php date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) and [time formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php) first by replacing the slashes with hyphens, and removing the miliseconds leaded by a colon.
Then you rely on the normal `strtotime` and `date()` functions.

```
$passedTime = "30/3/2020 17:7:23:847";

// Replace hyphens with slashes
// Comply with notation:
// Day, month and four digit year, with dots, tabs or dashes: dd [.\t-] mm [.-] YY
$compatible = str_replace('/', '-', $passedTime);

// Remove trailing miliseconds based on position of third (last one) colon
// Comply with notation:
// Hour, minutes and seconds    't'? HH [.:] MM [.:] II
// It's also possible to replace the last colon with a dot to keep the miliseconds
$compatible = substr($compatible, 0, strrpos($compatible, ':'));
// $compatible = "30-3-2020 17:7:23"

$date = strtotime($compatible); 
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date); // "2020-03-30 17:07:23"
```