# This string date "10/05/2025" is not converting to dateformat php

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code below :

```
$startDate= str_replace('/', '-', $bhishi_date);
$startDate=strtotime($startDate);
$startDate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate))
```

Comment: You can use just the last cmd like `$startDate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('10/05/2025'))`;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string to Date and DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime)

Comment: But it is not working !!!

Comment: `But it is not working`... yes it is - demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/20fdc4d95f07a30c7c3e334c6731040f76624fe6. Adapted to your situation: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/52154a75c2ebf8cc74f9e198d06902571d360e1b  That's assuming of course that 10/05/2025 is supposed to be 5th October, and not 10th May. If it's the latter, the lesson from that is not to pass dates around in ambiguous formats. If you need to parse from a specific format, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

> Try Below Code its help for you.

```
   $startDate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($bhishi_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Carbon` too:

```
$startDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('10/05/2025');
```

Answer (score 0):

To deal with dates and times, I prefer to use the build-in [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with which you can do everything in a consistent syntax.

```
$startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '10/05/2025')->format('Y-m-d');
//                  input format ---------^^^^^   output format ---------^^^^^
```