# Compare two dates w/ times on different string results

Tags: php, datetime

So I'm having some trouble comparing two times, and I wanted to see if someone might be able to assist me:

So I have the following first modified date/time:

```
Debug::dump($global_post->modified);
```

Which returns:

```
string(19) "2022-07-26T18:06:42"
```

---

Then I have my second modified time which is this:

```
$post = static::get_by_corporate_id($global_post->id);
$post_modified_date = $post->get_post_modified();
```

Which returns:

```
string(19) "2022-07-26 18:06:41"
```

Now I'm attempting to utilize the `DateTime:diff()` method to compare `$global_post->modified` and `$post_modified_date` and return true if they match, otherwise, return false.

How would I be able to reliable compare them when they are formatted differently?

Comment: Parse them first https://stackoverflow.com/a/6239199/529282, of course, you need to know the exact format used, otherwise, you can't tell if 2022-02-07 means July 2nd, 2022 or February 7th, 2022.

Comment: @Martheen, how would you parse the first one with the `T` (timezone) inside the string?

Answer (score 2):

Simply by doing this, for example:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2022-07-26T18:06:42');
$date2 = new DateTime("2022-07-26 18:06:41");
dd($date1 == $date2); //boolean
```

Comment: Smart and short

Answer (score 1):

I will create new dates from character strings:

```
$date = new DateTime('2022-07-26T18:06:42');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').PHP_EOL;

$date2 = new DateTime('2022-07-26 18:06:41');
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
```

Then:

```
if( $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') == $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ) {
    echo 'yes';
    return true;
}
```